# Weird characters downloading files from FTP

Tags: windows-10, ftp, filezilla, web-development, charset

Since a while I experience problems downloading files from all FTP servers. This mainly concerns for example .css and .js files. When these files are downloaded, strange characters appear in the files, making them unusable.

I spoke to my hosting provider, he even watched, but he cannot reproduce the problem.

I work with a Windows 10 computer. Filezilla is the software that I work with. My IDE is Phpstorm.

**Screenshot of relevant Filezilla settings**

- https://prntscr.com/obzh9j
- https://prntscr.com/obzhzi
- https://prntscr.com/obzi6s

**Example:** https://prntscr.com/o8zg9f

The problem is probably due to a wrong character set, although I have not changed any settings. I also turned off my firewall, but that didn't help either.

Hopefully you can help me with new tips. If further information is needed, I would love to hear from you!

Comment: Do these files contain non-ASCII (non-latin) characters?

Comment: https://dierennamengids.nl/beheer/assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.css This is the original, working file. @harrymc

Comment: I can't see any non-ASCII characters here. Strange. Try maybe to download the file in default transfer mode of Binary, rather than Auto.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. But the question is why this is suddenly neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When FTP transfer causes strange characters, this almost always means a wrong
transfer type.

The example file you gave seems to be in ASCII, but I have not checked all the
characters.

Your transfer mode is Auto, which means that Filezilla decides automatically
on the transfer mode. Evidently it made a wrong decision.

In such a case, it is better to force the Binary mode, so as to transfer
the file as-is, no matter its encoding.
The Binary mode is slower, but for small files such as `.css` and `.js` the difference
in speed is minimal.